# How do I remove the pale line between events in a Highcharts columnrange chart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to create a timeline using a columnrange Highcharts chart. When I add several of the same event types, Highcharts separates them with a pale line.

I added `borderWidth 0;` but it didn't remove the pale line.

[picture with trouble](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYfq4.png)
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ardoxer/u3eWz/330/)

```
$(function () {
 $('#container').highcharts({

     chart: {
         type: 'columnrange',
         inverted: true
     },
     title: {
         text: 'Equipment Status'
     },
     xAxis: {
         categories: ['Status']
     },
     yAxis: {
         type: 'datetime',
         title: {
             text: 'Timespan'
         }
     },
     plotOptions: {
             series: {
        states: {
            hover: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }
    },
                        columnrange: {
                    pointPadding: 0,
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    borderColor:'red',
                    groupPadding: 0,

                }
     },
     legend: {
         enabled: true
     },
     tooltip: {
         formatter: function () {
             return '<b>' + this.x + ' - ' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%e %B %H:%M', this.point.low) +
                 ' - ' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%B %e %H:%M', this.point.high) + '<br/>';
         }
     },

     series: [{
         name: 'Producing',
         data: [{
             x: 0,
             low: Date.UTC(2013, 07, 03, 0, 0, 0),
             high: Date.UTC(2013, 07, 03, 4, 0, 0)
         }, {
             x: 0,
             low: Date.UTC(2013, 07, 03, 4, 0, 0),
             high: Date.UTC(2013, 07, 03, 5, 0, 0)
         }, {
             x: 0,
             low: Date.UTC(2013, 07, 03, 5, 0, 0),
             high: Date.UTC(2013, 07, 03, 6, 0, 0)
         }

         ]
     }]
 });
```

});

Comment: what you want exactly? can you please elaborate?

Comment: I want to draw solid without any border timeline, But i get the folowing result
https://i.gyazo.com/d7c5590cf040a4c2bf1dd565d1591396.png .How to remove these white pale lines?

Comment: That behaviour is already reported as u bug https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/6132 Maybe setting rendering-shape to crispEdges helps - http://jsfiddle.net/u3eWz/331/

Comment: Yes! that's worked. Thanks.
Can you add your solution like answer?

Answer (score 0):

The thick one bar which you are getting is due to the `x:0` on all the datasets. When you will use this, I assume they won't all have the same data. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ardoxer/u3eWz/330/